# Filter Specific Column Based on Search Results

Tags: sql-server, sql-like

I have a search bar and an HTML table that is populated from my sql server database. Whenever  I search, it uses a `LIKE` command on `SKU` and `SKU Description` to filter the table. When the results are displayed, I want it to filter the results based on what matches the `SKU` column the most.

For example, if I search for `"100"`, it will display results where that are located in either the `SKU` or `SKU Description` columns. BUT, I want it to filter so that the values matched in the `SKU` column are filtered to be seen first before the values that are matched in the `SKU Description` column.

I assume it's just a matter of adding something to my query, but how would I do this?

**Here is my query:**

```
$query = "SELECT Product_ID, [Major Category], [Minor Category], [Product Report Code], SKU, [SKU Description], [SKU Status], CAST([Create Date] AS DATE) AS Date, Group_ID, [SKU Group]
          FROM vProducts
          WHERE CONCAT(SKU, [SKU Description])
          LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";
```

Comment: Do you need matches from both columns or do you need only from SKU even match exists in SKU Description?

Comment: I need matches from all columns...Im pretty sure the answer from @manderson works for me though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be overkill, and you'll have to format this to your "$query". Here's the sql.

```
SELECT A.Product_ID, A.[Major Category], A.[Minor Category], A.[Product Report Code], A.SKU, A.[SKU Description], A.[SKU Status], A.Date, A.Group_ID, A.[SKU Group], A.Sort
FROM (
        SELECT Product_ID, [Major Category], [Minor Category], [Product Report Code], SKU, [SKU Description], [SKU Status], CAST([Create Date] AS DATE) AS Date, Group_ID, [SKU Group], 1 AS Sort
        FROM vProducts
        WHERE SKU LIKE '%' + @value + '%'

        UNION all

        SELECT Product_ID, [Major Category], [Minor Category], [Product Report Code], SKU, [SKU Description], [SKU Status], CAST([Create Date] AS DATE) AS Date, Group_ID, [SKU Group], 2 AS Sort
        FROM vProducts
        WHERE [SKU Description] LIKE '%' + @value + '%'
    ) A
ORDER BY A.Sort
```

Comment: Pretty sure this works! I just switched out the `+` for a period (`.`) and changed `@value` to my php variable